# How to apply VIMRC to my python file?

Tags: vim

I'm using Ubuntu13.10   My $HOME is /home/mario.

I execute vim in the terminal and used :e $MYVIMRC to set up my own preference.

I've test it inside that VIMRC file by typing :so $MYVIMRC,  it works!

But later when I changed my directory to /home/mario/LPTH and use vim ex45.py to open my python exercises.

Then I found I can't apply it to my python file by typing :so $MYVIMRC or :source $MYVIMRC
I even restart my computer, still can't work.

What happend? How can I apply the VIMRC to my python docuemnt?

Thanks for your help.

---------------------------addtional information part 1---------------------------------

Yesterday when I raised up this question, I've already set several configurations. such as:

```
set number
set expandtab
set tabstop=8
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
:syntax on
```

I can apply my configurations for this MYVIMRC file. which shows code numbers,for example. But when I open my python files in ~/LPTH. nothing happens. I checked this morning, still the same.

--------------------addtional information part2--------------------------
Obstacle hacked!!!!!

Previously: I followed tutor from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimrc,my execution is:

cd ~  ---> vim ---> :e $MYVIMRC ---> add my setting.

And it caused the problem.

This morning: I did the following executions.

cd ~ ---> vim .vimrc ---> add my setting.

And it works. Just that simple.

Thank you guys for your help

Comment: Does `:echo $MYVIMRC` show what you expect?  Maybe `:scriptnames` will give a clue as to the problem.  Try adding `:let this_variable_does_not_appear_anywhere_else = 'foo'` at the top of your vimrc file, so you can test whether it has been `:source`d.

Comment: @benjifisher  Hi, I've tried :echo $MYVIMRC, nothing happened. I tried the :scriptnames. It appears that the first path as "/usr/share/vim" I entered in to that directory and opened vim. I typed :e $MYVIMRC to edit, and type :wq to quit. But it shows "You can't open the archive to write in it" How could I change the system vimrc set. I'm sure it's on "/usr/share/vim". My user vimrc is on "/home/mario". But as I mentioned before. My change for its vimrc could only apply to the vimrc file. Can't infect my py files on /home/mario/LPTH. I've also tried :source d and :let bla = "foo", Error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't (need to) apply your `.vimrc` to a file. The configuration and customization commands that you put in there are automatically executed by Vim on startup. You should only put general stuff like `:set listchars=... backupdir=...` in there, and any general `:map`pings.

Some settings are specific to a programming language like Python; Vim has *buffer-local* options (like `:setlocal expandtab`) and mappings; these can be set by *filetype plugins*. Some people define those via `:autocmd FileType python setlocal ...` directly in their `~/.vimrc`, but it's better to just configure `:filetype plugin on` there and then place the specific options in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already you dont need to apply your .vimrc to a file. You just need to have your .vimrc file in your $HOME directory, it will automatically be executed by vim.

This is the .vimrc i would reccomend for Python

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set lines=40  
set columns=80
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4   
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set smartindent
set smarttab
set retab
set autowrite
set autochdir
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```